# Dependency injection in a sub class MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, subclass, superclass

Given a class

```
public class TopicPost : ForumBase
{
}
```

and its super class

```
public class ForumBase
{
}
```

I want to be able to perform dependency injection on my super class, so it becomes:

```
public class ForumBase
{
    protected IUserUtilities _userUtilities;

    public ForumBase(IUserUtilities userUtilities)
    {
        _userUtilities = userUtilities;
    }
}
```

so now, in my Subclass (TopicPost) I have to add a constructer like so:

```
public class TopicPost : ForumBase
    {
        public TopicPost(IUserUtilities userUtilities) : base(userUtilities)
        {
        }
    }
```

Which ultimately means that when I instantiate TopicPost, I have to do so like this:

```
TopicPost post = new TopicPost(new UserUtilities());
```

My understanding was that I wanted to not have to 'new' up a userUtilities object if I am using dependency injection.

Is there any point to using DI if I have to instantiate the object myself? Didn't I ultimately want to leave the job of instantiation to my container? Isn't that the whole point of DI?

EDIT:

to clarify, I am instantiating TopicPost by Selecting into it from an EF call:

```
 var topic = query.Select(t => new TopicPost
            {

                    TopicId = (int)t.TopicId,
                    ContentId = t.ForumTopic.ContentId,
                    Body = t.ForumTopic.ForumContent.Body,
                    GravatarHash = t.ForumTopic.ForumContent.AspNetUser.Email

            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

In this scenario I am unable to pass a UserUtilities object in my instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it does not make much sense to inject these dependencies to entity classes. They should be just dumb POCOs.

With dependency injection, you should not try to new up your objects (except in the case of writing unit tests for a class). Your dependency injection framework will inject the implementation of your interface wherever you need that object, based on the **interface -> implementation** registration you provided to the framework.

For example, If you were to use the Unity framework,  you will register your interface->implementation mapping like this

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        return container;
    }
    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IUserUtilities , UserUtilities >();
        container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    }
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
    }
}
```

And you will call this Bootstraper in the Application_start event inside the global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    Bootstrapper.Initialise();  // Call the bootrstraper
}
```

Now wherever you want an implementation of your `IUserUtilities`, you can use constructor injection

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly IUserUtilities userUtilities;
   public HomeController(IUserUtilities userUtilities)
   {
      this.userUtilities=userUtilities;
   }
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       // use this.userUtilities;
      // to do : return something
   }
}
```

Comment: Those classes are not entity objects, they are in fact POCOs. This answer doesn't really address the question of dependency injection in super class and it does not resolve the scenario I presented.

Comment: It does not matter whether it is derived or base class, your dependencies will be available there in ForumPost.

Comment: If I try and create a TopicPost without newing up a UserUtilities object it tells me there is no constructer that takes zero arguments.

Comment: Yes. So wherever you are doing that, (Ex : inside your controller/service class, you use DI to get an instance of `IUserUtilities` (like i have in the answer) and use that  as the parameter `var a=new TopicPost(this.userUtilities);`

Comment: OK yeah, I see what you mean. I'm not at my PC so can't test this out. However I'm creating the topicpost by selecting into a new topicpost on a select statement to EF so not sure how that would work.

Comment: I am unable to pass a UserUtilities object as part of my instantiation. Please see my edit question above

Comment: If it is a simple POCO entity class, why are you passing this dependency to that ? Do not mix the entity with the service. Do whatever you need to do with userUtitlities in another place, after you execute your LINQ query

Comment: I guess I have my answer and its not possible to do what I am trying to do.  It seems a little restrictive to me. The data being retrieved in my query needs to be manipulated before it is displayed, it seems inefficient to do this in a separate action, causing me to have to loop through my data an extra time before display